# How to get these event notifications on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

When seeing  [EMBRACE+](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/embraceplus/embrace-a-smart-piece-of-wearable-technology?ref=category) ， I wonder how it can get all event notifications on iOS . Some system event notifications and third-party application notifications ,without JailBreak and private APIs.

[image: event notifications]

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: "Set colors that match my outfit"?  What?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it maybe is a BT2.1 device.So the developers can use Message Access Profile (MAP) to read the calls , messages and Email...
As for the facebook or skype,I thought that this APPs have their SDK for developers to read the notification.
Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is the full Bluetooth MAP protocol supported by Apple now ?